# asp.net, Silverlight, Visifire

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, charts, visifire

I am developing one chart application on .net framework by  using Silverlight and Visifire, Its a silverlight application and I am running it on localhost.
I have connected through SQL server database to my application and it is running fine, The main thing that i am looking for is that, when i change data inside the database, It should dynamically change my application's chart values.

What I tried is, I set the page refreshing parameter in my web page and its updating the values also, but whole application is re-appearing.

So, Is there any way to change the chart value parallely as I change my values in database.

Looking forward for response,

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a timer in your silverlight control that polls the database every x min's but this will make alot of calls to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "DispatcherTimer" in Silverlight application and call UpdateChart() on each tick event of the timer. Checkout the sample code below.

```
public Page()
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); // 10 sec
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateChart();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for response but the main thing is that what i'll write inside that update method.

Comment: You can write dataSeries.DataSource = myCollection;